# Keyevent getID causing error

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

I am trying to make a game where the character is a 75x75 object, and he moves around the screen. However, when I run my code, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid display mode
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(Unknown Source)
at sylvyrfysh.Screen.setFullScreen(Screen.java:17)
at sylvyrfysh.ImageDrawer.run(ImageDrawer.java:26)
at sylvyrfysh.ImageDrawer.main(ImageDrawer.java:17)
at sylvyrfysh.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I am not sure what is causing this, as I made another project with the same DisplayMode arguments, and it worked fine.
package sylvyrfysh;

```
import game.infos.Information;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageDrawer extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4278324581016693552L;
    public static void main() throws InterruptedException{
        DisplayMode dm=new DisplayMode(Information.sX,Information.sY,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        ImageDrawer i=new ImageDrawer();
        i.run(dm);
    }
    private void loader(){
        bg=new ImageIcon("src/sylvyrfysh/maze_icon.png").getImage();
        chara=new ImageIcon("src/sylvyrfysh/char.png").getImage();
    }
    private void run(DisplayMode dm){
        System.out.println("HI");
        loader();
        s=new Screen();
        s.setFullScreen(dm,this);//error here
        repaint();
        while(EHandler.run){
            if(rp){
                repaint();
                rp=false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
        g.drawImage(bg,360,0,null);
        g.drawImage(bg,720,0,null);
        g.drawImage(bg,0,480,null);
        g.drawImage(bg,360,480,null);
        g.drawImage(bg,720,480,null);
        g.drawImage(chara,imgX,imgX,null);
    }
    private Image bg,chara;
    Screen s;
    public static int imgX=0;
    public static int imgY=525;
    public static Boolean rp=false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the specific reason for using display mode ? Is it for achieving full screen window ?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to change graphics device's 
display mode is platform- and configuration-dependent and may not always be available. `GraphicsDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported()` should be used to check prior to change the display mode on graphics device.

Some other important suggestion are made [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/displaymode.html) nicely.

Comment: Before I set fullscreen, though, i do check if change is supported.

Comment: this answer should be comment i think. My bad :(

Comment: Turns out my monitor can do 800x600, but not 750x600. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: :) damn i should have said that. Anyway you are always welcome.